# Setting up the WatiN COM Interface from WatiN Test Record

Tags: php, watin

Using PHP code

```
$iface=new COM("WatiN.COMInterface");
$ie = $iface->CreateIE("http://www.google.com");
$ie->TextField($iface->FindByName("q"))->TypeText("watin");
$ie->Button($iface->FindByName("btnG"))->Click();
```

From http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/WatiNCOM.html

Result in `com_exception: Failed to create COM object 'WatiN.COMInterface': Invalid syntax …`

Other COM like

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
```

is working fine .

Could someone give a step by step manual of how to make WatiN work with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't registered the WatiNCOM assembly for COM interop.

Try running the following from a command line in the directory containing the downloaded files.

```
regasm WatiNCOM.dll
```

this command is documented here: [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help 
When I ran this 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>RegAsm C:\xampp\htdocs\myStuff\_TMP1\WatiN\WatiNCOM.dll

The result was:
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.4016
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: So I tried also this
 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322>RegAsm C:\xampp\htdocs\myStuff\_TMP
1\WatiN\WatiNCOM.dll
RegAsm error: Failed to load 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myStuff\_TMP1\WatiN\WatiNCOM.dll'
because it is not a valid .NET assembly

What should I do now?

Comment: @WaylonFlinn   What should I do now?

Comment: @Itsik Looks like you might need to install nUnit. WatiN makes pretty extensive use of it.

Comment: @WaylonFlinn do you know how to do it? I have VS2008

Comment: @Itsik NUnit is open source unit testing software. You should be able to download it from their website. After you download and install, you might have to copy the 'nunit.framework' assembly into the same directory as the WatiNCOM assembly.

Comment: @WaylonFlinn  I have installed the nUnit and copied the nunit.framework to the same directory but still get this error 
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Versio
n=2.4.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its depen
dencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
I cannot find version 2.4.0.2  also is it important where I keep all the DLL should it be in system32? I use Vista Buisness SP2

Comment: @Itsik Make sure you download and install version 2.4. The file name will start with 'NUnit-2.4.0-r2-'. You can find it in the 'Older Releases' section of this page: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download

Comment: @WaylonFlinn Thanks! i realize it - but still i have a problem - now I'm trying to install it in system32 - Can you run WatiN in PHP? Is there is other way you can help me - I'm in NY

Comment: @WaylonFlinn still not ok..

I’m using this command 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>RegAsm C:\xampp\htdocs\myStuff\_TMP1\WatiN\WatiNCOM.dll /regfile:c:\1\myTest.reg
Then I run the myTest.reg
I must do it that way seen that I’m getting this error 
RegAsm : error RA0000 : An error occurred while writing the registration information to the registry. You must have administrative credentials to perform this task.  Contact your system administrator for assistance
So I’m creating the myTest.reg file and run it – all is without an error but when I’m back in the PHP

Comment: @WaylonFlinn Running the code above I’m getting com_exception: Failed to create COM object `WatiN.COMInterface': The system cannot find the file specified
Am I referring to the correct files (in RegAsm and PHP)?

Comment: @Itsik Seems puzzling but I think you're almost there. Update here when you get it figured out and I'll make sure to update the answer.

Comment: @WaylonFlinn sorry but I do not know what to do know .. it is not working - so what is the next step? Am I running the correct files from the correct location? I really do not know more what to do

Comment: @Itsik You may need to do one of the following: (1) specify the codebase option on regasm (2) install the assembly in the Global Assembly Cache. See here for (2) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682 (you probably just need to do step 6)

Comment: @WaylonFlinn Thanks! and this will help for the PHP?

Comment: @Itsik Once you get it installed as a COM object it should work fine in PHP.

Comment: @WaylonFlinn when I do step6 
C:\Windows\system32>gacutil -I C:\xampp\htdocs\myStuff\_TMP1\WatiN\WatiNCOM.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Failure adding assembly to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a s
trong name

Comment: @WaylonFlinn and doing step1-5 is not clear to me how this will be linked to the WatiN dll - ... :(

Comment: @WaylonFlinn is regsvr32 a solution? anyway also here I have an error - The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

Comment: @WaylonFlinn the more I'm busy the more I see that the problem is that "the assembly must have a strong name" - we can add the assemble using  .NET Configuration 1.1 from Control Panel\Administrative Tools - select Assembly Cache and click in the menu Action / Add.. - but as mentioned we have the strong name issue and what to do now I do not know ;(

Comment: @Itsik Sounds like the assembly wasn't given a strong name so you won't be able to put it in the GAC. Try copying all the files to the same directory as the php script.

Comment: @Itsik It looks like your other two options are (1) running regasm with the '/codebase' parameter and (2) putting all the files in '%SYSTEMROOT%\system32'. You may also be able to fix the problem from the php side by modifying your include path (set_include_path()).

Comment: @WaylonFlinn I do not know why, but nothing helped despite your kind help – seen we did all, I think that the DLL’s from WatiN are not ok. Anyway thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @Itsik You're welcome man. I'm sorry we couldn't figure it out.